# How can I teleport seamlessly, without using interpolation?

Tags: minecraft-modding, bukkit, non-euclidean

I've been implementing Bukkit plugin for creating toggleable in-game warping areas that will teleport any catched entity to other similar area.

I was going to implement concept of non-Euclidean maze using this plugin, but, unfortunately, I've discovered that doing `Entity.teleport()` causes client to *interpolate movement while teleporting*, so player slides towards target like Enderman and receives screen updates, so for a split second all underground stuff is visible.

While for "just teleport me where I want" usage this is just fine, it ruins whole idea of *seamless teleporting*, as player can clearly see when transfer happened even without need to look at debug screen.

Is there possibility to somehow disable interpolating while teleporting without modifying client, or maybe prevent client from updating screen while it's being teleported?

Comment: The Teleport Tethers from [Additional Pipes](https://bitbucket.org/Kyprus/additionalpipes/wiki/Crafting) might do something along these lines, but I think they only keep chunks loaded at the server, not at the client

Comment: ...and also spout: http://www.spout.org/threads/spoutplugin-recommended-build-1212-for-craftbukkit-1-2-5.3501/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vanilla Minecraft implemented seamless relative teleports recently ([link](https://twitter.com/Dinnerbone/status/420956915578179584)), you might be able to get away with just having the server execute a command:

```
Bukkit.dispatchCommand(Bukkit.getConsoleSender(), "tp player 0 0 0");
```

Comment: As I've seen no solution to this problem those times, I've just gave up and started work on my own engine :) Thank you for your answer, however, it seems to work very smooth, almost as good as mine implementation :)